# Multiply two columns in BIRT

Tags: java, eclipse, reporting, birt

I am new in birt report tool.In my requirement i am calling 2 functions through query(Two separate datasets.ie dset2 and dset3) which yield 2 columns.Table is bind to another dataset(ie:dset1).Now i need to show these 2 columns along with another column by multiplying these 2 columns.How can i do this BIRT?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which version of BIRT you are using, the answer following uses 4.2.1, but should also apply to earlier versions.

You have already created your two source data sets, next step is to create a joined data set.

- Right click on "Data Set" in the outline, and select "New Joint Data Set"

After the two data sets are joined you can create computed column, that multiplies the two columns.

You will of course have to recreate your table and bind it to the new joined data set.